# Troubleshooting Specific Button Visuals: How to Modify Individual Buttons Using CSS in Taipy

Tags: python, css, user-interface, taipy

I'm new to Taipy and CSS and currently facing an issue where I'm unable to modify the visual appearance of specific buttons using CSS.

Although I tried changing the '*class_name*' of a particular button in my *.css* file, it didn't work as expected. While I could change the visuals of all buttons with the '*class_name*', I couldn't do the same for specific buttons.

To clarify, let's assume I have three buttons: **Button A**, **Button B**, and **Button C**, which by default have blue text and a blue border. However, I want to change only **Button C** to have a different color or no border while keeping the other two buttons unchanged. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to change a specific button's appearance, the most straightforward approach is to use the Taipy "id" property. In Taipy, each visual element can be given an "id" that will serve as a unique identifier to change it in CSS.

For example, let's say you want to add an "id" property to a button. You would put it directly in your visual element.

```
<|Open/Close|button|id=open-button|>
```

In this case, the button has been given the "id" attribute "open-button".

Now, you can use this "id" in your CSS file (*main.css* if the Gui is running in *main.py*) to target only this specific button and change its visual properties. Here is how you can do it:

```
#open-button {
     color: red;
     border: none;
}
```

In this example, we are using "#open-button" to target the button with the "id" of "open-button". We are then changing its text color to red and removing the border. You can customize the CSS properties based on your desired look.

You can check the documentation of Taipy for styling [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/styling/#using-the-html-id-attribute). It also answers your specific question.